# Overflow hidden scroll-y cutting off content

Tags: html, css

I've pasted the code below. It appears that the addition of the title element causes content to be cut-off from the bottom of the scroll. If I remove the title element, no content is cut off. The title shuffles down and impacts the next element.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7olsG.png)

HTML

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Some long content here...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

If a box shadow and border radius is added to the wrapper element, this causes further strange behaviour (if overflow hidden removed from wrapper as well).

[image: with box shadow and border radius]

Comment: what do want to achieve ?

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: @Niteesh Look at the screenshot. The last line is cutted-off.

Comment: @Niteesh I want to solve the scroll issue. The screenshot image shows that although the scrollbar is at the bottom, the content is not visible.

Answer (score 4):

The error occur because you are setting content height as 100% , so it takes the height of it's parent wrapper, but wrapper also contains titile div which occupies some area of 100% height, so the scrollbar scrolls for the height : (wrapper- height of title). So, try this :

```
.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

Comment: @aprilone the error occur because you are setting content height as 100% , so it takes the height of it's parent wrapper,  but wrapper also contains titile div which occupies some area of 100% height, so the scrollbar scrolls for the height : (wrapper- height of title)

Comment: Please, don't use comments to complete the answer, just edit it! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Change overflow-y to scroll

Answer (score 0):

The overflow of `.wrapper` is hidden so it cuts off the content of children content. Simply remove the `overflow:hidden` and it will behave as you want.

Code snippet:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  line-height: normal;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...
  </div>
</div>
```

**If you for some reason can't delete `overflow: hidden`** you can calculate the height of content using `calc` so it won't be cutted off.

Code snippet (using calc):

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  line-height: normal;
  height: calc(100% - 26px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...Some long content here...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like the correct answer. Although, if I do some further styling with border radius and box shadow on the wrapper, there are no rounded corners and the box-shadow falls short of the bottom.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you send a screenshot? I will update my answer if you can't delete `overflow: hidden`. But I don't recommend my second solution, try to avoid using `calc` if it is possible.

Comment: I have added a second screenshot to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Because you add hidden in main container,
Add scroll in main container.

```
.wrapper {
  border: 0;
  overflow: scroll; /* change it */
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `height: 100%;` on the `.content` *plus* the height of the `.title` element *will* be cut off in a parent that hides overflow and is 100% high - just because 100% plus anything else adds up to more than 100% => causing an overflow, which will be cut off due to `overflow: hidden`.